# FlowLayoutPanel slow loading of UserControls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel`that loads a bunch of usercontrol I've created.

This is the usercontrol(let's name it `ColorBox`), it's just an image (loaded on a `Panel`) with a label.

[image]

I load these into a `FlowLayouPanel` and this is the final result:
[image]

My problem is that the loading is very slow when there's a lot of ColorBox (300-400). 
As of right now I'm calling the function that loads the items in a separate thread so the UI is still functional.

This is the function that I use to load, I profiled my app and it's the one that takes a lot of time:

```
    private void LoadColorBox(List<ColorBox> cBoxList)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        foreach (var cBox in cBoxList)
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cBox);
        flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

Another function that takes a lot of time is the constructor for the `ColorBox` object, especially where I check if the `Image` I'm using exists and then put it on my panel.

```
      Image img;
      using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(imgPath))
      {
            img = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
      }

      panelColor.BackgroundImage = img;
      panelColor.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

What can I do to improve performance ?

Comment: How many controls?  Where are the images coming from?  When do you load them?

Answer (score 0):

You should use AddRange() instead of looping Add().

```
private void LoadColorBox(List<ColorBox> cBoxList)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.AddRange(cBoxList)
    }
```

I don't know when you are processing this, but you could also gain some time if you do this kind of stuff in the constructor of the form instead of the Load (or some other) event.

Comment: I tried with AddRange() and performances are exactly the same. After some digging I think that the problem could be with the creation of the ColorBox object. I'll update my question.

Comment: Have you tried to create your bitmap directly on the panelColor.BackgroundImage Property. Something like panel.Color.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(imgPath) ?